# Facing problem while exporting static html with next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

[image]I'm a newbie in react. I've done a project and for static HTML export, I used "next build && next export" in package.json, and npm run the build command. It also gives me an out folder. The problem is when I try to access HTML files from our folder locally and with a live server, It shows only HTML content without CSS and js.
I tried many ways but can't figure out the problem.
If anyone helps me with this, I'll be very very thankful to him.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

next export allows you to export your Next.js application to static HTML, which can be run standalone without the need of a Node.js server. It is recommended to only use next export if you don't need any of the unsupported features requiring a server.

If you're looking to build a hybrid site where only some pages are prerendered to static HTML, Next.js already does that automatically

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried only with export but it's giving me an error. For running export I need to first run build. If I done this, It's giving me the same problem I told.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem.
In my case, Changing `src` value solved the problem.
Here is the exact steps.

1. build your project
2. inside build folder there's index.html
3. change `<script src="/static/js/12345.js">` to `<script src="./static/js/12345.js">` **(add "." before "/")**
4. Do same thing to `<link href="/static/css/main.b57f21b0.css" rel="stylesheet">`  and `<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>` and `<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/>` and other file structure string if exists.
5. You solved the problem.

Comment: 6. Don't forget upload fixed files to a server!

Comment: Many many thanks for your reply. It's working but still showing two error in browser console. Can you help me about this. Thanks in advance